# Uvc with Lots of Magic... Enjoy the Show!

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, alphametic

### Puzzling Weekend! UVc is back again with Lots of Magic... Enjoy the Show!

Given:  LOTS is being multiplied by F to yield MAGIC.

Digit 0 to 9 are all represented by ten different letters in this multiplication Alphametic.

LOTS, MAGIC represent two concatenated Numbers.

$ LOTS $  X  $F$    =  $MAGIC$

Clues:

1)  F represents 3,

2). M, G, C are consecutive, but may not be in order.

3). A, I are also consecutive.

4). Also, LOTS contain 3 consecutive digits not necessarily in order. One of the consecutive  digits adds upto rest of the two consecutive digits.

Figure them out and Enjoy the Show!!!

Comment: the rest instead of test?

Comment: Thx for catching it.

Comment: welcome:) according to (4), the 3 digits must be 1,2,3. yet F=3. possible error?

Comment: F is the multiplying digit...I wanted to bring it down to show it better..LOTS is being multiplied by single digit F to yield MAGIC.

Comment: i mean will one of LOTS repeat with F?

Comment: There are ten letters representing ten digits.

Comment: in your perspective, are 9,0,1 "consecutive"?

Comment: What @OmegaKrypton is saying is that consecutive integers $k$, $k+1$, $k+2$ satisfying the last condition forces $k+k+1=k+2\implies k=1$, in turn forcing the largest consecutive digit to be $3$, but this is already taken by $F$.

Comment: thanks for the check, but shouldnt @JonMarkPerry get it instead? thanks!

Comment: As per the voting record below..you answered at 15.30..John answered at 15.35..I went by that for accepting

Comment: I mean the first one to get **the final answer** gets the check. Nonetheless, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial

$M=$

> $1$ or $2$

Since $F=3$

> Even if $L = 9$, $M$ would also be $2$. Carry is not possible since $M$ would then be 3 ($M=F$)

$L>$

> $3$ (since only then there would be carry)

Answer (score 5):

It's:

> $5694\times3=17082$

Because:

> $F=3$. $M=1,2$, and so $MGC=\{0,1,2\}$, but $C\ne0$. As $M+G+C=3$ and our answer is divisible by $3$, $3|(A+I)$, so $A+I=4+5, 7+8$. From clue 4, $A+I=7+8$, and $LOTS=\{4,5,6,9\}$. $S=4$ as $3\times4=2$, and no other value produces an output in the range required, so $C=2, M=1, G=0$. The rest I guessed.

Comment: Note that last hint that the sum of two consecutive digits in LOTS must add up to the third, but $4+5\ne 6$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire; I think he means $4+5=9$.

Comment: How did you deduce M = 1,2 ?

Comment: @NoLand'sMan; LOTS is at most 9876, which would make M=2, or it could be 1. I assumed it was not zero, because leading zeroes are frowned on.

Comment: Note `\mid` for $\mid$.